# Regex (perl) that will match (globally) one or more spaces occurring other than at the beginning of the line

Tags: regex, perl

My understanding is that `/[^\A] +/mg` will match globally one or more spaces occurring other than at the beginning of the string or just after newline.

Apparently, I'm wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "         word1     word2\n     word3     word4     word5\n";
print "str before = $str\n";
$str =~ s/[^\A] +/ /mg;
print "str after  = $str\n";
```

Output:

```
str before =          word1     word2
     word3     word4     word5

str after  =  word word2 word word word5
```

The desired output is:

```
str before =          word1     word2
     word3     word4     word5

str after  =          word1 word2
     word3 word4 word5
```

So the leading spaces are preserved in number but multiple spaces occurring after the beginning of each line are reduced to a single space.

I'm not finding what I'm looking for in `perldoc perlretut` nor `perldoc perlre` (even after searching through all the instances of "[^" with `/\[\^`). Many thanks, in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity -- why was this question unworthy of a single upvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, the most simple solution is: `s/\S\K +/ /g;`

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/D8ICiE)**.

Comment: changes the meaning a little.  `s/[^ \n]\K +/ /g` (or the \K-less equivalent `s/(?<=[^ \n]) +/ /g`)

Comment: I've switched to this as the accepted answer (from @m-buettner's, though it was useful and highly educational to parse out) since it works and is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot use `\A` in a character class, since it is not a character. You could go with two negative lookaheads though:

```
$str =~ s/(?<!^)(?<! ) +/ /mg;
```

That makes sure that the match can neither start after the beginning of a line nor after another space. The latter condition is important, otherwise if you have multiple spaces at the beginning of a line, the regex would simply start matching from the second one.

By the way, to increase readability when using literal space characters in regular expressions, a neat trick is to wrap them in a character class:

```
$str =~ s/(?<!^)(?<![ ])[ ]+/ /mg;
```

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/jYID9o)

Comment: Why just don't use `\K` as suggested by Ωmega? This is Perl :)

Comment: @Jay - m.buettner's pattern is more general, not just for Perl, which may help others with same problem with other languages where `\K` is not supported.

Comment: @Jay because I wasn't aware of it. That's why Ωmega got my upvote. And surely you don't even need `\K`, if you just capture what's in front of there (which would then even work for users of JavaScript finding this question). There are loads of other possibilities. But do you really think that's worth a downvote?

Comment: @Jay oh, fair enough. Sorry, since the downvote coincided with the time of your comment I assumed your comment was an explanation for the downvote. But apparently it was just another downvote that didn't go with an explanation at all :-/. Sorry, didn't mean to accuse you or anything.

Answer (score 0):

As [m.buettner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633117/m-buettner) says, a regex like `[...]` is a *character class* and contain only characters, not patterns. In fact your code generates the warning

```
Unrecognized escape \A in character class
```

But a string of spaces that's not at the start of the line is a string of spaces preceded by a non-space, so all you need to write is this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "         word1     word2\n     word3     word4     word5\n";

print qq(String before = "$str"\n);

$str =~ s/[^ ]\K +/ /g;

print qq(String after = "$str"\n);
```

**output**

```
String before = "         word1     word2
     word3     word4     word5
"
String after = "  word1 word2
 word3 word4 word5
"
```